# Access to the outside value from Java Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, filtering, java-stream

I have the sample code below

```
String value="xyz";
dataList.stream().filter(obj -> obj.equals(value))
```

My question is: how to have the `value` available in my lambda expression in Filter.

Comment: You should be able to use it directly unless you are *assigning* to it more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is directly accessible if you are using Java 8, see the below code.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        String value="xyz";
        List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataList.add("abc");
        dataList.add("def");
        dataList.add("ghi");
        dataList.add("xyz");
        dataList.add("jkl");
        dataList.add("mno");



        dataList.stream().filter(obj -> obj.equals(value)).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, Eclipse was giving me compilation error as I was typing the variable name in my lambda expression. Its good now!

Comment: okay. may be it was because of language level not set to Java 8 earlier.

Comment: @rohit12sh Maybe you changed `value` later. Lambdas can use only use variables which are either declared as `final` or are *effectively* final (they don't change).